# Error in gwt-rpc

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt-rpc

I created a RPC service which created a SportsLeagueAndroidRequest in the appengine shared folder. When I am running to try my project it shows an error

[ERROR] [sportsleagueandroid] - Deferred binding result type 'edu.columbia.sportsleagueandroid.shared.SportsLeagueAndroidRequest' should not be abstract

SportsLeagueAndroidRequest is an interface generated automatically when you create a RPC service!!

How can I remove this error?

```
final EventBus eventBus = new SimpleEventBus();

final MyRequestFactory requestFactory = GWT.create(SportsLeagueAndroidRequest.class);
requestFactory.initialize(eventBus);

sendMessageButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() 
{
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) 
{
    //String recipient = recipientArea.getValue();
    //String receivers[] = recipient.split(",");
    String message = messageArea.getValue();
   // setStatus("Connecting...", false);
    sendMessageButton.setEnabled(false);
    sendNewTaskToServer(message);
}
private void sendNewTaskToServer(String message) {
    SportsLeagueAndroidRequest request = requestFactory.sportsLeagueAndroidRequest();
    StadiumProxy task = request.create(StadiumProxy.class);
```

Comment: It is same as on the lines of https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_add_rpc#add_data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final MyRequestFactory requestFactory = GWT.create(SportsLeagueAndroidRequest.class);
```

You are invoking `GWT.create` on a `RequestContext`. It needs to be invoked on a `RequestFactory` as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory#interface).

You need to create an interface that extends `RequestFactory` as in the example I linked to. If you look in your `sendNewTaskToServer` method, you are actually calling `sportsLeagueAndroidRequest()` from `SportsLeagueAndroidRequest`. See? You should be calling `sportsLeagueAndroidRequest()` from your `RequestFactory` interface that you previously created with `GWT.create`.

The RequestFactory lifecycle looks something like this:

1. Create a new `RequestFactory` using `GWT.create(MyRequestFactory.class)`
2. Create a `RequestContext` using `myRequestFactory.myRequestContext()`
3. Fire a request, using `myRequestContext().myDomainMethod().fire()`